# State of C++ Standard

Tags: c++, standards

I haven't kept up lately with the C++ world.  Exactly where do things stand these days regarding the standard?

Is TR1 adopted?

Is there a TR2?

How do these relate to C++0x?  Are the subsumed?

Has a decision been reached on threading yet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find an extensive article about the upcoming C++0x on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x) and the current state of C++ evolution [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2705.html). It is also worth giving a look at the current GNU implementation in [gcc](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html)

Comment: Thanks.  Excellent sources.  The GCC link was a great addition.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend you to visit
 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/

Answer (score 2):

The information you want is available at the site **pvnsp** directed you to.  To synopsize my understanding

- Yes, [TR1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1745.pdf) has been adopted and [C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x) is expected to subsume *nearly* all of the standard.
- There is a [TR2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1810.html), it's still in development.
- As far as I know, there is no decision on threading.  Here's a document from [open-std.org](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1875.html) that discusses the matter.